# Realtek RTL8188EE wifi-adapter not working on ubuntu gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, ubuntu-gnome, realtek-wireless

I have Hp 15-af152ur [w4x36ea] laptop and i installed common 16.04 ubuntu after windows 10. Wi-fi worked good, ethernet the same, but then i changed os to ubuntu gnome, and after it wi-fi adapter isn't working. Then i wrote this commands to run third-party driver:

```
    git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
    cd rtlwifi_new
    make
    sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188ee
    sudo make install
    sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
```

After it i did reboot and wi-fi worked good. But after some reboots and shutdowns driver turned-off and i needed to write

```
    sudo modprobe -rv rtl181ee
    sudo make install
    sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
```

and reboot my laptop again to get wi-fi running. What should i do to run driver automatically?
My wireless adapter is Realtek RTL8188EE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i solved my problem by myself. I created script with that code and modified file in this directory

```
    /etc/rc.local
```

with this code:

```
    /usr/sbin/scriptname
```

After every reboot/shutdown script runs when os is loading. I made like 5 reboots and wi-fi is still working.